# How can I check for internet connection before running /etc/rc.local script

Tags: boot, vpn

I want to use the Raspberry Pi as a VPN gateway. The RPi connects to my home network and the internet via `wlan0, and` any device plugged into `eth0` gets a VPN connection. I am using `pptp-linux` to make the VPN connection and everything worked fine during my prototyping stage. However, to complete the project I have put the VPN connection in the `/etc/rc.local` script so that it will start at boot. Now it fails 50% of the time. I suspect that it is attempting the VPN connection before I am properly connected to the internet via `wlan0`. If this is the problem, I need a test for a valid internet connection at the beginning of `rc.local` before proceeding with the rest of the script.
Any ideas as to how I could do this?

Comment: You could add a `sleep 20` before your script. Or better, put your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d`. That way the script is run once the network interface goes up.

Answer (score 7):

From [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932187/334274);

> Ping your local gateway;
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null && echo ok || echo error
> ```

Answer (score 4):

right off the top of my head:

1. ping your router
2. ping google.com
3. grep `ifconfig` output for valid gateway and/or valid IP address

Comment: You would need to `grep` the pings for a valid reply. In a while loop until all conditions are met. Just pinging wont do much. Jivings quoted a good line of code.

Comment: @ppumkin no need to use `grep`, ping uses exit codes to tell you about the results, something like `ping -qc 1 192.168.1.1 && echo ok || echo error`

Answer (score 4):

Based on Jivings sample code and some of my own logic.

```
#!/bin/bash

STATE="error";

while [  $STATE == "error" ]; do
    #do a ping and check that its not a default message or change to grep for something else
    STATE=$(ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null && echo ok || echo error)

    #sleep for 2 seconds and try again
    sleep 2
 done

#put your VPN code here...
```

The proper way would be to create a function that returns a boolean on the while comparator. but this is how the shell logic should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Debian now uses upstart. This is probably a much simpler way of doing it that init.d scripts.

You may need to try a few different services to wait on, but `networking` (if it's there) or `network-manager` might be a good ones to try first.

This is for Ubuntu, but you shouldn't find too many differences http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/